# I am 15, what is a recommended non bull-crap workout routine?

Tags: workout-routines, muscle

I am 15 and I am 6 feet tall, I weigh 'bout 145 pounds (last time I checked), I am currently doing about 35-40 pushups and about 50-60 sit-ups every night. Then, every wednesday I go to Krav Maga, on a very ambitious level, with random workouts, like scissor, bike, burpies, pull ups, sit ups, palm push ups, fist push ups and resistance.

My question is whether this is a good routine, I am called skinny but chest muscle covers up, and will it affect my height for the better or worse? (better being taller)

Comment: When asking if a routine is good, you have to ask "is it good for X"? There are routines for strength, for mass, for weight-loss... And they are all different. Please state your goals, and once you know them, search the site for routines that accomplish what you want - im sure there already are tips for any goal you might have.

Comment: Is it a good routine? Probably not. Doing a relatively small number of pushups and situps, especially at 145 pounds, is going to quite rapidly become ineffective. But, as KL already said, you need to decide what your goal from a routine is. If you're interested in increasing strength and building mass, Stronglifts 5x5 is popular (and something I'd like to try, but I'd have to convince my gym to buy a power rack); plenty of information on here about that one.

Comment: It used to be thought that weightlifting at younger ages stunted growth, but more recent studies are starting to refute that. They've found that inactive, unhealthy diet type individuals have faster plate closure than active people. Unless you have an injury, it's unlikely that weightlifting will stunt growth.

Comment: @K.L. Im trying to gain strength, and on the way, I guess, some mass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good routine? Bad routine? Towards what end? What is your goal?

If it's to be "more fit" for Krav, your listed routine likely will work because the bodyweight work will bring enable your body to work with itself better, handle the intensity of a Krav class, etc..  But if you want to get bigger and stronger, that routine won't take you very far. Bill Kazmaier didn't get as he did because of pushups.

You did later comment you are trying to gain strength and more mass. So if that is your goal, I would recommend looking at the [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.com) program by Mark Rippetoe. What you want to pick up is his book, *[Starting Strength: Basic Barbell Training](http://aasgaardco.com/store/store.php?crn=199&rn=413&action=show_detail)* (presently in it's 3rd edition). This book is squarely aimed at people in your shoes: young guy that ways to get bigger and stronger. Mark lays out a very logical program based upon fundamental barbell-based movements: bench press, squat, deadlift, press, power clean. The program is simple, straightforward, and has proven results.

If you put in the work to follow the Starting Strength program, eat big (consider GOMAD), then the size and strength will come.